# I can't see underwater

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I cannot see underwater in Skyrim. Every time I go underwater everything is completly blue.
I recall being able to see underwater before when I began to play the game but now I can't

Comment: What Platform are you playing on? Because if you are on PC, you can change the following settings in SkyrimPrefs.ini: bDoDepthOfField=0 iRadialBlurLevel=0

Comment: Screenshots might help. As always, if you have not updated your video drivers. Do so please.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on PC, get [this mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14007/?). I played on XBOX before, and I was able to see underwater, however when I transferred my save file to PC and started playing there I couldn't, before I installed the mod obviously.